# How to onClickListen MP Android line Chart Circles?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to listen the click on the circles at the Line Chart .. but I could not. So please help me.

```
chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {

    }
});
```

I tried this but it did not work!.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell from the code you provided but I ran into this issue when I called `chart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false)`

From the names "highlight" versus "selected" if wasn't clear at first sight that the `setHighlightPerTapEnabled` method also disables the `OnChartValueSelectedListener`

My solution was to replace the `OnChartValueSelectedListener` with a `OnChartGestureListener`. Here's a snippet of what I implemented:

```
private class BarChartGestureListener implements OnChartGestureListener {
    private int _lastTappedIndex = -1;

    /* ... */

    @Override
    public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me) {
        final Entry entry = _barChart.getEntryByTouchPoint(me.getX(), me.getY());
        if (entry != null && _lastTappedIndex != entry.getXIndex()) {
            final Object data = entry.getData();

            // TODO: Insert your magic here...
        }
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

In the `onChartSingleTapped` you can get the `Entry` that was tapped and programmatically highlight it or whatever else you want.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `OnChartValueSelectedListener` this interface and override these two methods as below

```
 @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),entries.indexOf(e)+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {
    }
```

and add listener on lineChart `lineChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);`
**Note:** 
Entries is list of Entry objects.
Toast will show clicked circle index value.